# How to change the preselection of suggested variable names in the Resharper intellisense

Tags: c#, resharper, intellisense

When I write a variable like `IndexFileRepository` and hit Ctrl+Space the Resharper intellisense suggests me following options:

```
FileRepository, IndexFileRepository, Repository, fileRepository, indexFileRepository, operator, repository
```

and preselects the last one - `repository`.

How can I make Resharper to preselect `indexFileRepository` automatically instead of `repository` like it does e.g. in IntelliJ Idea? I'd like to avoid pressing the up/down arrows all the time.

Note: continue by typing `ind` or camel case `ifr` doesn't help either:

for `IndexFileRepository ind` it suggests:

```
index, indexFile, indexFileRepository
```

and for `IndexFileRepository ifr` it suggests:

```
ifFileRepository, ifIndexFileRepository, ifRepository, ifrFileRepository, ifrIndexFileRepository, ifrRepository
```